# passing JSON object to a function which is value of <option> in dropdown list

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to pass value of on `<option>` in `<select>` on a button press. 
None of the ways I tried are worked.

```
<select id="mySelect2"> 
    <option>Model Series</option>
<option value="{'varId':'4dr Sedan ','monthYear':'08\/1995 - 05\/2001'}">My Sedan  08/1995 - 05/2001</option>
....
...
</select>
```

I want to pass this JSON object as parameter to a javascript function ob press of a button:

```
<button onclick="display(document.getElementById('mySelect2'));"> Go </button>
```

How can this be done?

On the other hand this works fine:

```
<select id="mySelect2" onChange="display(this) >
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid: `value="{"varId":"4dr Sedan ","monthYear":"08\/1995 - 05\/2001"}">4dr Sedan`. That opening quote before `varId` is actually interpreted as the closing quote of `"{`

Comment: So the `display` function is suppose to take a JSON string as a parameter?

Comment: @Musa yes. It needs to take JSON object as variable. It works fine if I call the javascript function from onchange() in select.

Comment: Ok got it working. needed to remove value and just pass the object. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Does it help to fix the quotes?

```
<option value="{'varId':'4dr Sedan ','monthYear':'08\/1995 - 05\/2001'}">4dr Sedan  08/1995 - 05/2001</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change the quotation inside the `value` to this:

```
<option value="{'varId':'4dr Sedan ','monthYear':'08\/1995 - 05\/2001'}">
```